# Completing the square of complicated expression (answer available)

Tags: calculus, arithmetic, completing-the-square

I would like to rewrite the following expression

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sigma_{\theta}^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{I}(\theta_{i}-\mu)^{2} + \frac{1}{\sigma_{0}^{2}}(\mu-\mu_{0})^{2}
\end{align}
$$

as a *square* with respect to $\mu$. I do not know how to complete the square, the answer should be

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\left(\mu - \frac{\sigma_{0}^{2}\sum_{i=1}^{I}\theta_{i}+\sigma_{\theta}^{2}\mu_{0}}{\sigma_{0}^{2} + \sigma_{\theta}^{2}}\right)^{2}}{\frac{\sigma_{\theta}^{2}\sigma_{0}^{2}}{\sigma_{0}^{2} + \sigma_{\theta}^{2}}}.
\end{align}
$$

What is the first step to do this? Write out the sum, or is there some trick?

Comment: A lot of algebra here.  You might start by defining $a$ to be the coefficient of $\mu^2$ (it will be the inverse of the 2nd expression's denominator).  Then find $b,c$ such that the expression can be written $a(\mu^2+b\mu+c)$. Then do the usual completing the square inside the parentheses.

Comment: I just realized that I have misinterpreted this exercise, the above expression is not actually what we rewrite as a square. First er have remove all terms of the expression that does not depend on $\mu$, then it should be possible to attain a perfect square.